# Class not being added to element

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out why the class isn't being added to a selected td element.

Example of a date cell in jQuery DatePicker table...

```
<td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2014">
    <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">1</a>
</td>
```

What I'm trying with jQuery...

```
<script>

    var dateList = [ 1, 10, 2014 ];

    $("td[data-month='" + dateList[1] + "'][data-year='" + dateList[2] + "']")
        .filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() === dateList[0];
        }).addClass("cal-selected-date");

</script>
```

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Added Return to $(this).text() === dateList[0];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to return the result in the `filter`:

```
return $(this).trim() === dateList[0];
```

*EDIT:*

Since your not selecting the `a` but the `td` instead, you also need to add a `.trim()` to trim off the whitespace.
And last but not least you either need to convert both to number or remove a single `=`

```
return $(this).text().trim() == dateList[0];
```

or

```
return Number($(this).text().trim()) === dateList[0];
```

Comment: Well using your example code I cannot see anything else wrong with it other than that `data-month` is 9 in your html and 10 in the array but since that's just an example that could have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Well spotted -- DatePicker must index at 0, but I scrolled to the next month and it still didn't have the added class.

Comment: Still not getting it, so I'll try and break this down into something a little simpler, and then build it up to the complete example.

Comment: Ok, so I tried this with just the <td> info inside a regular table and it worked just fine, so I think the problem is something with the jQuery UI DatePicker. 

Marked as solved. I'll investigate this further, but at least I know the selector code is working. A big thank you to you and SatPal.

Answer (score 1):

You missed `return`

```
$("td[data-month='" + dateList[1] + "'][data-month='" + dateList[2] + "']")
    .filter(function() {            
        return $(this).text() === dateList[0];
    }).addClass("cal-selected-date");
```

Alternatively you can use .`data()` in filter

```
$("td")
    .filter(function() {
        return
            $(this).data('month') == dateList[1] &&
            $(this).data('year') == dateList[2] &&
            +$(this).text() === dateList[0]; //Convert text to number using +
    }).addClass("cal-selected-date");
```

Comment: I liked the alternative example, but unfortunately it isn't working.

Comment: Thanks, I got your code example working, but the problem seems to be with jQuery DatePicker. Marked as solved. Thanks for your help :)